# Piping content from Github into crontab

Tags: cron, pipe, curl, github

I'm not in front of a testing environment right now but I desire to download a Bash script with `curl` and then load its content into crontab.

The content as appears in Github raw document is for example:

```
0 0 * * * ... 
0 0 * * 0 ...
```

Is this code template looks okay to you?

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/file.sh | crontab
```

Comment: You said `curl by default outputs to stdout`. I think I understand you: The pipe works on `stdin` therefor it will fail, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl` outputs to `stdout` by default so

```
curl URL
```

is enough. And at least on macOS `crontab` needs a `-` to read from `stdin` so we end up with

```
curl URL | crontab -
```

Whether it is wise to load unverified data from an URL directly into Cron is another question though...

Comment: Thanks, the data is verified from my personal Github account.